# Проблемы с проектом PHP, связанные с autoload'ом файлов(Composer)

Tags: php, composer

Здравствуйте, у меня есть PHP проект, делал его на локальном сервере(OpenServer), для автоподгрузки использовал Composer. Перед выгрузкой на удаленный сервер сделал еще раз `composer update`, чтобы обновить зависимости, загрузил, перешел по URL и пишет "..  Uncaught Error: Class '\Admin\Controller\ErrorController' not found in ...". Что может быть не так? Почему Composer не цепляет зависимости? 
Я вручную сидел вписывал в файле загрузки проекта перед стартом: 
`require_once '...'`, но так очень долго и можно что-то упустить

---

$res = require_once 'autoload.php'
Вот print_r($res)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вся суть Composer:

```
function myAutoload ($class) {
    $class=str_replace("\\",DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$class);
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/" . $class . ".php");
}
if (!empty($client)) {
    foreach($client->_classmap as $class){
       spl_autoload_register("myAutoload");
    }
}
//$client - класс, в котором есть зависимости
```